# Running a .VHD on a virtual machine with different hardware

Tags: virtualization

If I create a virtual hard disk snapshot of my machine, can I run that image on a different computer via virtual box or virtual PC?

Will there be hardware compatibility issues or does the virtualization software solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

This is the beauty of virtualization, the hardware is abstracted from the system.  You will be able to run the VHD from another virtual host, such as hyper-v or virtualbox.  You should install the hosts virtualization extensions program to give it the proper virtual device drivers.